# git-diff - Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc

Tags: git, git-diff

Look at `git help diff` it says:

```
git-diff - Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc
```

I understand `changes between commits` but not `changes between commits, commit` or `changes between commits, commit and working tree`.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: I think it's meant to be read *changes between commits*, OR *changes between commit and working tree*, OR something else.

Comment: remember "etc." contains an implied "and", which is a good tipoff that "commit and working tree" is a single item

Comment: @Jubobs yes, that makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

Well, with `git-diff` you can show changes `between commits`:

```
git diff <commit> <commit>
```

Or `between commit and working tree`:

```
git diff <commit>
```

And a lot more other options as can be seen [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).